# How to fix texturing in DirectX9

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

I try to draw terrain using Directx9.
I set vertices and indices, but it's not work well.
some polygons are not visible like this picture.
why some polygons are not drawn? How do i fix this problem.
help me please.

code below is a part of the after unlock vertex and index buffer.

MYINDEX struct contain three index each word type.

TERRAINVERTEX struct contain DXVECTOR3 for position 
and DXVECTOR2 for uv coordinate.

[image]

```
TERRAINVERTEX v;
pv = (TERRAINVERTEX *)pVertices;

MYINDEX i;
pi = (MYINDEX*)pIndices;

int offSet = 0;

for (int z = 0; z < m_iCz-1; ++z)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < m_iCx-1; ++x)
    {
        // left top
        v.point.x = (float)((x - m_iCx / 2) * m_vfScale.x);
        v.point.z = -(float)((z - m_iCz / 2) * m_vfScale.z);
        v.point.y = 0.0f;

        v.texture.x = 0;
        v.texture.y = 0;
        pi->i_0 = offSet++;
        *pv++ = v;

        //right top
        v.point.x = (float)(((x+1 - m_iCx / 2) * m_vfScale.x));
        v.point.z = -(float)((z - m_iCz / 2) * m_vfScale.z);
        v.point.y = 0.0f;

        v.texture.x = 1;
        v.texture.y = 0;
        pi->i_1 = offSet++;
        *pv++ = v;

        //left down
        v.point.x = (float)(((x  - m_iCx / 2) * m_vfScale.x));
        v.point.z = -(float)((z + 1 - m_iCz / 2) * m_vfScale.z);
        v.point.y = 0.0f;

        v.texture.x = 0;
        v.texture.y = 1;
        pi->i_2 = offSet++;
        *pv++ = v;

        ++pi;

        //right down
        v.point.x = (float)(((x + 1 - m_iCx / 2) * m_vfScale.x));
        v.point.z = -(float)((z + 1 - m_iCz / 2) * m_vfScale.z);
        v.point.y = 0.0f;

        v.texture.x = 1;
        v.texture.y = 1;
        pi->i_0 = offSet++;

        *pv++ = v;

        //left down
        v.point.x = (float)(((x + 1 - m_iCx / 2) * m_vfScale.x));
        v.point.z = -(float)((z + 1 - m_iCz / 2) * m_vfScale.z);
        v.point.y = 0.0f;

        v.texture.x = 0;
        v.texture.y = 1;
        pi->i_1 = offSet++;
        *pv++ = v;

        //right top
        v.point.x = (float)(((x + 1 - m_iCx / 2) * m_vfScale.x));
        v.point.z = -(float)((z - m_iCz / 2) * m_vfScale.z);
        v.point.y = 0.0f;

        v.texture.x = 1;
        v.texture.y = 0;
        pi->i_2 = offSet++;
        *pv++ = v;

        ++pi;
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like one of your 2 triangles is backface-oriented towards the camera; try changing the vertex order to "right down, right top, left down"

Comment: You have a copypasta problem: left down is defined as right down

Comment: thank you guys. I fix it. copypoast and backface cull were problem.